# PhpStorm - permute reverse selection

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, sublimetext

I switched from sublime text to phpstorm recently and missing the permute reverse selection feature from sublime (CTRL+T on windows).

More clear:
Swapping selections with each other.

From

```
xxx
yyy
```

to

```
yyy
xxx
```

Do you guys know if there is something equivalent in PhpStorm? I didn't find anything in the www.

Comment: 2020, still no solution >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after days of research this feature does not exist in PhpStorm, unfortunately.
I'll contact JetBrains.

Thanks though.

7 years later: it's now possible without plugins. The action is called Transpose (Edit → Transpose).

Comment: Was it successful? Still can't find that one.

Comment: Sadly still not available. Will ping the JetBrain team again.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146675 here's a feature request to vote for

Answer (score 1):

### Maybe you help a option from awesome plugin [String Manipulation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162)

`Menu` → `Edit` → `String Manipulation` → `Swap Characters/Selections`

---

#### Configure hot-keys

- `Settings` → `Keymap`
- Search *"Swap Characters"* and select line
- `Add Keyboard Shortcut`(press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- Set your shortcuts
- Press `Apply` and `OK`
- Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to moves lines up and down which should have the desired effect.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this isn't what I want.
I want to swap the selected text with each other.
For example:
`code
This line stays in place but 123 should swap.
This line stays in place but this should swap.
`
I only want that "123" goes to "this" and "this" goes to "123".

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to show up settings dialog. On the left menu, select `Keymap`. In the search box on the right, you can type to find commands shortcuts. Also, the first button at right of that search box allows you to search a command by its shortcut.

Perhaps doing a little research with these two features you can find what you need. I'm not sure if PhpStorm has such feature (swapping selections), though.